# How to set Firebase rules that allow authenticated users to only read and write their own data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My database structure is:

```
users
  david@gmail.com
    records
      ApK2DFpG87NDGYutgAVO
        pulse: 80
      Bryd87NAS20dfDGYtghg
        pulse: 78
  eva@fb.com
    records
      A81hxASDKH38dhaj9321
        pulse: 93
      A82ndasklih38ASD2eda
        pulse: 67
```

and rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{email} {
      allow create, read, update, delete: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
  } 
}
```

I would like every user (e.g. `foo@gmail.com`) to be able to read and write data only under that user (`users/foo@gmail.com/**`).

When I read `users/me@gmail.com` in the Rules playground (while being authenticated as `me@gmail.com`), I get "Simulated read allowed", as expected.

However, when I read `users/me@gmail.com/records` from my app (while being authenticated as `me@gmail.com`), I get:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

What am I missing?

By the way, why the Rules playground doesn't allow reading collections (e.g. `users/me@gmail.com/records`)? It says:

> Path must be document-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of the recursive wildcards of version 2 of the security rules, as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{email}/{document=**} {
      allow create, read, update, delete: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
  } 
}
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards), it will match documents in any subcollections of the `users` collection as well as documents in the `users` collection.

---

> By the way, why the Rules playground doesn't allow reading collections

If I am not mistaking, this is because [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), and therefore you need to exactly specify the document you want to target in the "Rules Playground".